# Temperature of empty space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, vacuum

Is the temperature of empty space defined? What is it?

I am not talking about the cosmos. I mean really empty space, without particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no particles or radiation there cannot be a [temperature](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temperp.html) defined as it is dependent on the average [kinetic energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360345/temperature-of-empty-space) .

[image: temperature] .

Now in the real universe there are no completerly empty spaces from particles or radiation. The cosmic microwave background radiation has a black body distribution [temperature of 3K .](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/bkg3k.html)